# Kube-api server not coming up on Baremetal

Tags: centos, kubernetes, etcd, flannel

I am trying to install Kubernetes on my laptop by following the instructions on http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/

I added the following IP's in /etc/hosts

`192.168.121.9   centos-master
192.168.121.65  centos-minion-1
192.168.121.66  centos-minion-2
192.168.121.67  centos-minion-3`

and have followed the procedure except for flannel installation.

I was going step by step of running instances with the following

`for SERVICES in etcd kube-apiserver; do 
    systemctl restart $SERVICES
    systemctl enable $SERVICES
    systemctl status $SERVICES 
done`

etcd started well, but kube-apiserver fails with the following error: 

`Nov 17 14:40:11 localhost kube-apiserver: F1117 14:40:11.842367    6176 controller.go:84] Unable to perform initial IP allocation check: unable to refresh the service IP block: error #0: dial tcp 192.168.121.9:2379: i/o timeout`

Tried adding 192.168.121.9 IP to the same interface in the BareMetal, but still failed.

Not sure what is the issue here..

Comment: I'm sorry. That guide looks pretty terrible. I tried reading through it but was having a hard time following what it was trying to do. I would recommend you try setting up the cluster with kubeadm. It's WAY easier, supports CentOS, and enables encrypted communication with TLS certificates between the nodes http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

Comment: @JustinGarrison you mean TLS between APIServer and slaves. I don't think the encryption covers communication between nodes per say: this is handled by the networking layer (i.e. Weave or other)

Answer (score 0):

The source of your issue is that the kube-apiserver cannot reach etcd, likely because it just started and is not completely up yet.

`2379` is the client port for etcd, and `192.168.121.9` is the resolved IP for the master node.

Why etcd either isn't taking requests, or isn't reachable by kube-apiserver will require further investigation.